# Show that $ \iint_{S} \nabla(f) \cdot d \vec{S} \neq 0$ at the following conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^1$ assume that $\nabla(f) \neq 0$ at every point in the surface $S$ such that $S=${$f(x,y,z)=0$}. you may assume that $S$ is smooth and bounded. Show that $$ \iint_{S} \nabla(f) \cdot d \vec{S} \neq 0$$

I read the solution for this problem it was written :

By the assumptions the surface S is smooth at each point, and its normal is $\nabla(f)$ we can write $$\iint_{S} \nabla(f) \cdot d \vec{S}=\iint_{S} \nabla(f) \cdot \frac{\nabla(f)}{\|\nabla(f)\|} d S=\iint_{S}\|\nabla(f)\| \cdot d S$$

**My questions is**:

1. how the fact that $S$ is smooth relate to the fact that the normal vector to $S$ is $\nabla(f)$?
2. if the gradient is the normal vector to $S$, why is it possible to write this solution? is it usually $d\vec{s}=\hat n ds$ while n is parallel vector to the surface?

Comment: Fix $p = (x_0, y_0, z_0) \in S$. $\nabla f(p) = 0$, there's nothing to be shown. Otherwise by implicit function theorem, you can (WLOG) find a $C^1$ functin $\phi$ from a neighbourhood of $(x_0, y_0)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that a neighbourhood of $p$ in $S$ is precisely $(x, y, \phi(x,y))$. Then the vectors tangent to $S$ at $p$ are precisely $(x_0 + x, y_0 + y, J(x,y))$ where $J(x,y)$ is the derivative of $\phi(x,y)$. Now show that $\nabla f$ annihilates those vectors, using $\langle \nabla f(p), v \rangle = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p+tv) - f(p)}{tv}$, so it must be normal to $S$ at that

Comment: When you write $d\vec S$, you presume that you have oriented your level surface $S$. This means you know what "outward-pointing normal" means everywhere on $S$ (and this notion varies continuously). Since $\nabla f$ points normal, it cannot switch from "outward" to "inward" without passing through being $0$. Thus, it points "outward" everywhere (so, positive flux) or "inward" everywhere (so, negative flux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface is defined by $f(x,y,z)=0$. The normal direction is defined by the gradient since the most efficient way to increase from a level curve is along a direction orthogonal to it. Hence, $n=\frac{\nabla (f)}{||\nabla(f) ||}$ is the unit normal direction.

From there, the claim is true because you are integrating a magnitude over a region where the vector is never zero. Hence, the integral is with respect to a positive integrand.

The "smoothness" assumption just makes the normal calculation more direct, in terms of the gradient.

Comment: so this claim is true even if $S$ is not smooth? if the answer is yes can you  explain what is the difference between those two scenerios?